unable to find valid certification path to requested target [Spring boot 3 - kafka]
I am trying to make a mtls connection between spring boot kafka consumer and remote brocker of my company which is configured with mtls.
My entrypoint files are: chain_bundle.pem and my_name.p12.

I tried first to generate keystore.jks and truststrore.jks files this way (passphrase is changeme):

keytool -import -file chain_bundle.pem -alias caroot -keystore truststore.jks -storepass changeme -noprompt

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore my_name.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS -srcstorepass changeme -deststorepass changeme


Then, in spring boot config, here is a code snippet:

spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: url-of-bootstrap-server:443
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: latest
      group-id: name-of-group-id
      security:
        protocol: SSL
      properties:
        max:
          poll:
            records: 1
            interval:
              ms: 1200000
      ssl:
        key-store-location: classpath:certs/v4/keystore.jks
        key-store-password: "changeme"
        key-store-type: "JKS"
        trust-store-location: classpath:certs/v4/truststore.jks
        trust-store-password: "changeme"
        trust-store-type: "JKS"

I already placed truststore.jks and keystore.jks under src/main/resources/certs/v4
I get this error:
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Any idea please ?

This question is similar to: Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

read https://blog.sachingurjar.me/resolving-the-pkix-path-building-issue/
